# How to hide the php action file name in php form post method

Tags: php

I have the different php file(process.php) to post the form data form login.html. I saw some of the website forms source code they did not give the direct .php file name. Instead they have given some folder name. I am trying to understand.

Comment: if they didn't specify a file name the form processor was likely an `index.php` file that apache had directory indexes turned on

Comment: Probably looking at a framework, but, you can accomplish what you are looking for with `mod_rewrite`, or an `index.php` file inside that directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, this is achieved using "mod_rewrite": a mechanism for rewriting URLs on the fly. See the Apache docs for more detail: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

The extension for a file/script can be altered or hidden using `mod_rewrite` rule in `.htaccess` file. Another scenario is the usage of framework. The url's in framework work under this concept `http://www.example.com/controller/function` .